# magento2 adding products via ProductRepositoryInterface

Tags: magento2, catalog

I am working on a module where I can add products by import.

This is my code: http://pastebin.com/DVkHVg0t

In my foreach I am creating a new object like this, because if I work with 
$this->product (ProductInterface) the data from the previous object is saved with my new product.

> $product =
>   $this->objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

Is there any better way for doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `CollectionFactory` like below :

Inject object of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory`
class in constructor

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
)
{
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;

}

public function import($resultSet)
{
    foreach($resultSet as $result) 
    {
      $product = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
      // your code..
    }
}
}
```

Comment: did the solution work for you ?

Comment: Yes that solution worked for me, thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Why are you using `ProductCollectionFactory` to create a product when you should use `ProuctFactory` instead?